# How to make a Javascript script run more than once in a page

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey, userscripts

My website has button A. When I click it a pop up div appears with yes no option. I must click yes. So I write a script so that when I click button A, the yes option is automatically clicked. It goes like this

```
buttonA.onclick = function(){
document.getElementById('buttonYes').click()
};
```

I load this into Tampermonkey. When the page loads, the code work for the first time. After that the button goes back to their original behavior. The Javascript somehome only works once when the page is newly loaded. Can someone suggest a way to make the code works all the time in the page and I don't need to reload the page for it to work.

Comment: Can you share the site you're working with so others can test it to reproduce the behavior and help find a solution? For one, `onclick` doesn't stack so I'd use `addEventListener`. Secondly, the `#buttonYes` element might only appear after a rerender, so you might want to poll or listen to mutations. But just a blind guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a private website. I open the website, use `addEventListener` in the console, click button A, and the button Yes is automatically clicked. When I click button A again, the button Yes is not automatically clicked and must be clicked manually. The code seems to work only once after I type it in the console. It doesn't work many times.

Comment: Does this button still have the same id after the popup opens the second time?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, it does. I will only work as I intended once after I enter the code into the console. If I want it to work again, I have to enter the code into the console again

Comment: I didn't see that before, but what is `buttonA`? Do you create it? Is it on the web page?

Comment: @RandyVU maybe you can produce a replica of it that's sanitized for public consumption? It's extremely difficult to solve a problem I can't see.

Comment: @RandyVU I have an idea for you. Can you please edit your question to add the HTML for the button that you are clicking *(maybe a few lines before and after the button, so we are sure to have enough)*